# Failed to load source for: /Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

Hi I have used telerik controls in my project. I used "telerik:RadScheduler" with "
    " stylesheet manager.
This controls works fine on my local machine but when deployed to test server I get the following error: 
***"The css stylesheet, Failed to load source for: /dotnet/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?... "***

> The Css stylesheet source link is href="/dotnet/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2008.3.1016.20%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen%3aeac793b3-98e6-41a6-90b1-e029d0d02234%3a348638f9%3ae081ff96%3a2b273692%3a2cfb35c4%3a950fbd9a%3ade780ebc%3ab10231fb"

**See full tag for above stylesheet link**

*
Failed to load source for: /dotnet/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2008.3.1016.20%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen%3aeac793b3-98e6-41a6-90b1-e029d0d02234%3a348638f9%3ae081ff96%3a2b273692%3a2cfb35c4%3a950fbd9a%3ade780ebc%3ab10231fb
*

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Web Resources troubleshooting [guide](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-web-resources-troubleshooting.html) over at Telerik and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, We have hosted the Application on Azure VM and also we deployed the application gateway. Application gateway firewall was restricted to load the Telerik resources i.e. Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd
We just **set the firewall on Detection mode** and everything was worked properly.